# Choosing points for a 2d Convex Hull

Tags: algorithm, points, convex

I am making one algorithm a day, and didn't make to finish this one recently.

I have a set of points that i draw, and now I'd like to chose pairs to draw lines between them so that when it's done they will form a convex hull.

My idea was to start from the one that has the lowest y- coordinate, and then go in CCW order, but I am not sure how to write a good algorithm for choosing the pairs.

This question is in fact very simple, it's just me who is a beginner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Graham scan algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan)? It actually uses coordinate-sorting and CW order.

Comment: Or indeed, any of the other algorithms on the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms